# Unity3D: Having trouble with moving the player horizontally

Tags: unity-game-engine, math

The issue I'm having is most likely not what you'd expect after reading the title. Basically I'm trying to create a third person Minecraft like movement system (To those who haven't played the game the principle is that the camera moves with the mouse, the player's rotation is relative to the camera's, the player's movement is relative to the player's rotation). Now the problem with what I've created is that the player's horizontal movement, instead of going to the right from the player's current rotation it kind of orbits around the camera. [Here is the image representing how pressing the D key would go (the A key is the same except it goes counter clockwise instead of clockwise).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oiyx9.png)

```
//this is the function that moves the player and rotates him acording to where the camera is looking
float horizontal = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
float vertical = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");

Vector3 forward = mainCameraTransform.forward;
Vector3 right = mainCameraTransform.right;

forward.y = 0;
right.y = 0;

forward.Normalize();
right.Normalize();
    
Vector3 moveDirection = right * horizontal + forward * vertical;

desiredMoveDirection = (moveDirection * speed * Time.deltaTime);

controller.Move(desiredMoveDirection);

transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, Quaternion.LookRotation (mainCameraTransform.forward), Time.deltaTime * 10f);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hard to say what is the problem base on the code that you provided (camera script is not in it), but I think it has something to do with how you are rotating your camera, here is a code that works for me and maybe it could help you:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ThirdPersonMinecraftController : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float movementSpeed = 10f;
    public float rotationSpeed = 100f;
    public float cameraDistance = 5f;
    public float cameraMinAngle = -5f;
    public float cameraMaxAngle = 45f;

    private Transform cameraBase = null;
    private Transform cameraPivot = null;
    private Transform cameraMain = null;
    private CharacterController controller = null;

    private float cameraAngle = 0;


    private void Start()
    {
        controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();

        cameraBase = new GameObject("CameraBase").transform;
        cameraBase.position = transform.position;

        cameraPivot = new GameObject("CameraPivot").transform;
        cameraPivot.parent = cameraBase;
        cameraPivot.localPosition = Vector3.zero;
        cameraPivot.localEulerAngles = Vector3.zero;

        cameraMain = Camera.main.transform;
        cameraMain.parent = cameraPivot;
        cameraMain.localPosition = new Vector3(0, 0, -cameraDistance);
        cameraMain.localEulerAngles = Vector3.zero;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        float horizontal = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        float vertical = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");

        Vector3 forward = cameraMain.forward;
        Vector3 right = cameraMain.right;

        forward.y = 0;
        right.y = 0;

        forward.Normalize();
        right.Normalize();

        Vector3 moveDirection = right * horizontal + forward * vertical;
        Vector3 desiredMoveDirection = (moveDirection * movementSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        controller.Move(desiredMoveDirection);
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, Quaternion.LookRotation(forward), Time.deltaTime * 10f);
    }

    private void LateUpdate()
    {
        cameraBase.position = transform.position;
        cameraBase.Rotate(Vector3.up * Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse X") * Time.deltaTime * rotationSpeed, Space.World);
        cameraAngle -= Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse Y") * Time.deltaTime * rotationSpeed;
        if(cameraAngle > cameraMaxAngle)
        {
            cameraAngle = cameraMaxAngle;
        }
        if (cameraAngle < cameraMinAngle)
        {
            cameraAngle = cameraMinAngle;
        }
        cameraPivot.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(cameraAngle, 0, 0);
    }

}
```

Comment: Ah, my fault I forgot to mention I was using Unity's cinemachine freelook camera for the LookAt and Follow functions. I'll definitely try out your code and come back to mark the answer as correct. For now I thank you for taking the time out of your day and answering :D.